# r conditionally replicate row in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row, conditional-statements, replicate

My data frame looks like this:

```
SIT LOC NB VAL
A a 1 0.256
A b 451 0.023
B a 2 0.123
B b 1 0.741
```

I would like to replicate NB times the rows. For example, I want the second line to be replicated 451 times. Then, I will not need anymore the column "NB" and this simplify the use of functions such as aggregate, etc.

Comment: I don't see how this would "simplify the use of functions such as aggregate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subsetting with `rep`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="SIT LOC NB VAL
A a 1 0.256
A b 451 0.023
B a 2 0.123
B b 1 0.741", header=TRUE)

DFrep <- DF[rep(seq_len(nrow(DF)), DF$NB),]
```